# SwingWorker publish() and process(List) out of order after Modal dialogue

Tags: java, process, swingworker

In a complicated Java app, I extend SwingWorker, so I can handle reading from a socket in the background. The socket provides a lot of data that's needed to update the GUI.

There's a special caveat - the server that's writing to the socket writes things in a very particular order, which the client relies on. Think of it as sending definitions of terms, and then uses of terms. If the app doesn't get the definitions first, it crashes or displays bad data. Not a problem because the server is careful to do it right, and the socket IS TCP so I get in-order delivery. It's straightforward: I read from the socket in my Worker.doInBackground function, parse it and call publish(). Over in Worker.process(List), I iterate through the list in order, processing the stuff the socket gave me. All good.

All good unless the server sends something that convinces the client to pop up a Modal dialogue box, which can happen early in the things it sends down. When the model box is up, the background thread continues to read the socket and call publish(), which is expected. But worket.process(List) (which, mind you, is the code that's put up the Modal dialogue box) starts getting called with things that are wildly out of order. It's likely still in the middle of processing the last List it was handed, and got called recursively by whatever event handling the Modal box is doing.

My notes say it's ok to do GUI stuff in, and only in, process(List). I assume it's not safe to do GUI stuff in doInBackground(). So popping up a dialog box, I assume, needs to happen in process(List).

Is there a way to tell the dialog box to stop calling doInBackground(), or process()? I don't want or need anything to run until that dialog box is dismissed. Is there a more clever way to to what I need done? The server is free to send new stuff at any time, and order is always going to matter, so I don't see when it's ever safe to put up a Dialog box.

I tried to synchronize, holding a lock while a dialog box is open, and having doInBackground wait on the lock object right before calling publish(). No dice - they are probably run by the same thread, and java locks are recursive. (And maybe if they weren't the dialog box would hang.)

I can think of a possible clumsy workaround. I could tag the order things arrive in doInbackground() with a sequence number, and in process) I could republish anything I get with a sequence number that's unexpected too high. But then I might end up in a tight loop until the dialog box is dismissed ("Item 1129 is too high. Republish. Item 1129 is too high. Republish...")

What's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood what you are asking 100% (let me know if my answer is "offtopic"), but I will give emphasis on this part:

> Is there a way to tell the dialog box to stop calling
>   doInBackground(), or process()? I don't want or need anything to run
>   until that dialog box is dismissed.

Using a lock variable is the way to achieve that. See my example. **Comments inside code.**

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    private JDialog dialog;

    public Worker() {
        dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        //Plays no role but since there is no frame (icon in task bar)
        //you might not be able to terminate the program
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        int times = 0;
        while (true) { //Worker runs forever

            //If dialog is visible, just wait it until it is closed
            if (dialog.isVisible()) { //or dialog.isDisplayable()
                Thread.sleep(10); //Rest cpu
                continue;
            }
            //Here you read the data from server and you publish things to GUI - "process" method
            if (times == 5)
                publish("dialog");
            else if (times == 10)
                publish("exit");
            else
                publish("chunk");
            times++;
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        String chunk = chunks.get(0);
        System.out.println("Processing....:" + chunk);

        //A dialog requested
        if ("dialog".equals(chunk)) {
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Dialog closed");
        }
        //Exit requested
        else if ("exit".equals(chunk)) {
            System.out.println("Ran process 10 times, exiting....");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Worker().execute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... the idea of polling on a flag seems clumsy, but if no one comes up with anything cleaner I'll accept this. Polling on a flag that's set true before I pop up the dialog and set false after the Dialog returns does seem to work.

Comment: @ScottM I think this is the one of the cleanest you will find...

Comment: Java needs to learn how to guarantee ordering of events - which is probably can't do as long as process() takes a List. Instead, process() should repeatedly call a getNextObject() function (and where it gets the next object from is no one's business, as long as they are always in order.)